# How can I use llvm-ar generated archive file?

Tags: clang, llvm

`llvm-ar` archives several LLVM bitcode files into a single archive library that can be linked into a program. The archive operation works as expected. Aslo, it is possible to use `llvm-nm` to show all the symbols in the generated archive.

However, I noticed the generated archive can not be used by the other standard llvm tools, for example, `llc`, `lli` and `llvm-link` directly.

In order to use the generated archived file, I have to extract all the bitcode files from the archived file and then use them directly by `llc`.

Questions:

1. Is there some more elegant or efficient way to use the generated archived file by `llvm-ar`?
2. Could clang use bitcode archived file directly as below:

```
// assumes hello.bc is valid bitcode file and it is built successfully
clang-3.8  -o main main.c hello.bc

// ar hello.bc into lib libhello.bca
llvm-ar-3.8 rcs libhello.bca hello.bc

llvm-nm libhello.bca // has below output

   hello.bc:
   ---------------- T outupt
                    U puts

clang-3.8 -o main main.c libhello.bca // has below error

  libhello.bca: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: So your question is specific to archiving BC files only or is it a combination of OBJ and BC?

Comment: My question is specific to archiving BC files and I update the question as well. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: What do you mean by `way to use`? `clang` can deal with bitcode archives right away.

Comment: @arrowd, I mean if the bitcode archives can be directly used by clang/llc/lli/llvm-link without unarchiving it. Could you give an example how the bitcode archives can by used by clang? Could you also specify the version of clang, please. I am afraid my clang version is 3.8, it might be too low for this usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLVM tools like `llc`, `lli`, `opt` and others can't operate on bitcode archives directly. You have to unpack it before running them. Alternatively, you can link archive items into one single bitcode file, but that's not the same as having the archive, so it depends if that suits you.

As for `clang`, you can pass bitcode archives along with source files and libraries, and it will do the correct thing - unpack it, run passes, compile to object file and link into the final binary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had spent one hour to figure out how to use clang to build bitcode archived file, but still failed... I added the code the in my question, could you kindly point out how to fix it, please?

Comment: `libhello` file should have `.bca` extension. `.ll` is for textual IR files, thus clang tries to parse it as text.

Comment: thanks for your tip, I changed .ll  extension to .bca, but it still does not work for me. I add the new error message in the question. PS: I also tried with clang-5.0, which does work, either. Thanks again.

Comment: Clang 5 is probably still too old. It works for me with Clang 9.

Comment: I had tried clang 9.0.0, it still does not work.May I know what your exact version of clang is ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you regenerate `.bca` file using `llvm-ar` from LLVM 9? My Clang is `FreeBSD clang version 9.0.1 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git c1a0a213378a458fbea1a5c77b315c7dce08fd05) (based on LLVM 9.0.1)`.

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried clang-11 (built from the git source). Could you kindly check if my llvm-ar arguments are correct? I used ```rcs```. Thanks.

Comment: Everything's looking correct. I'm a bit lost why it isn't working for you, sorry.

Comment: I also built exactly your clang version from source, but I still have the same error message, which makes me a little bit crazy. I will try to understand why. Thanks for your effort and help.

Comment: I just got an idea. Does adding `-fuse-ld=lld` to clang command line change anything?

Comment: thanks for your help again. I tried, but it seems there is no option ```-fuse-ld``` for clang command ???

Comment: Then your clang is certainly too old. Try Clang 9 again, it does support `-fuse-ld` flag.

Comment: For me, `-fuse-ld` made the difference using Clang 9.